# MongoDB equivalent to Python's enumerate()

Tags: mongodb

I'm searching for a MongoDB aggregation to replace an array

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

by something like

```
[ {"i":1,"element":"a"}, {"i":2,"element":"b"}, {"i":3,"element":"c"} ]
```

Thanks

Comment: can you explain more, what is your input and what you have in collection?

Comment: Yep sorry. I'm dealing with songs : I have a field named "lyrics" which is a an array of strings (we can name them "lines"). I want to add next to each line its number (1,2,3,4 etc)

Comment: *I want to add next to each line its number* is it your input? how it will decide 1 will go to element "a" and also for other elements?

Comment: in ascending order : first element is 1, second is 2 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate loop of range from 0 to length of `lyrics` array using `$range`
- `$add` to add 1 in current index because range is started from 0
- `$arrayElemAt` to get specific element from `lyrics` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      lyrics: {
        $map: {
          input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$lyrics" }] },
          in: {
            i: { $add: ["$$this", 1] },
            element: { $arrayElemAt: ["$lyrics", "$$this"] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Doez8mRnNGH)

Comment: Actually there is a little problem : if two lines are the same it labelize them with the same number... any clue ?

Comment: see i have updated answer with correct solution.